# How to see which MySQL partitions are chosen?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, explain

I'm running a query against a partitions table but the performance is terrible.
I have a feeling that it is doing a full table scan instead of just a scan of two or three partitions.
The partition key is in the where clause.

Is there a way I can check what partitions it looked at to answer the query?
Is there an EXPLAIN that could tell me which partitions it will use?

Any tips for using partitions in JOINs?

I'm using MySQL 5.6.11

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS 
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id=tbl2.id
```